# Barplot of dummy categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.2

set.seed(123)

dat <- tibble(
  mcq_option_1 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
  mcq_option_2 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
  mcq_option_3 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
  mcq_option_4 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
  mcq_option_5 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

My goal is to create a barplot of the times each mcq option was selected (counts of 1s in each column). What is the quickest data manipulation technique to achieve this? Should I pivot longer first and then create a new count variable using mutate? Or can I quickly do this inside of the ggplot function?

Is there a shorter/better solution than this?

```
new <- dat %>% pivot_longer(
  cols = everything(),
  names_to = 'options',
  values_to = 'active'
)

new %>% filter(active == 1) %>% group_by(options) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to know the number of `1`s in a vector of `1` and `0`, you can simply take the `sum`. This can be done inside `ggplot::stat_summary()` by specifying `fun = "sum"`. This avoids some of the extra steps you introduce with `filter()`, `group_by()` & `summarize()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
dat <- tibble(mcq_option_1 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),  mcq_option_2 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),  mcq_option_3 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),  mcq_option_4 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),  mcq_option_5 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100))

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = 'options',
               values_to = 'active') %>%
  ggplot(aes(options, active)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "sum", geom = "bar")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This does work in this case, but note that `stat_identity` doesn't provide a sum -- it gives you a stacked bar plot with one group per observation. You can see this if you try to apply a border: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ex53.png
Even without a border, it can cause weird artifacts depending on your graphics device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CJIJ.png

Comment: Thanks, good point! I'll have to fix my answer.

Comment: Thank you!! I haven't used the stat_summary before.

Comment: [This](https://yjunechoe.github.io/posts/2020-09-26-demystifying-stat-layers-ggplot2/) is a great blog post to help you get oriented to using the `stat_*()` layers.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're looking for better execution speed or simply shorter code. You can at least get the code a bit shorter by first summing across columns, then pivoting.

```
dat %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = sum)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought about using sum. I was thinking only about counts.